# How to achieve "true" asynchrony

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

In his answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790468/is-it-possible-to-await-an-io-operation-that-is-not-declared-as-async-if-not-w), [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) refers to "fake" asynchrony and "true" asynchrony.

> there's a much easier way to schedule work to the thread pool: Task.Run.
>
> True asynchrony isn't possible, because you have a blocking method
>   that you must use. So, all you can do is a workaround - fake
>   asynchrony, a.k.a. blocking a thread pool thread.

How then is it possible to achieve true asynchrony, like the various methods in `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`?  Aren't all "truly asynchronous" methods just blocking operations on some other thread if you dig deep enough?

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov -- Why did you add the c# tag?

Comment: So this question would get broader attention. And it is C# related.

Answer (score 8):

> Aren't all "truly asynchronous" methods just blocking operations on some other thread if you dig deep enough?

No. Truly asynchronous operations don't need a thread throughout the entire operation and using one limits scalability and hurts performance.

While *most* truly asynchronous operations are I/O ones, that can get too overly complicated to understand. (For a deep dive read [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) by Stephen Cleary).

Let's say for example that you want to `await` a user's button click. Since there's a `Button.Click` event we can utilize `TaskCompletionSource` to asynchronously wait for the event to be raised:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
_button.Click += (sender, EventArgs e) => tcs.SetResult(false);
await tcs.Task;
```

There's no non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` so I use a `bool` one with a dummy value. This creates a `Task` which isn't connected to a thread, it's just a synchronization construct and will only complete when the user clicks that button (through `SetResult`). You can `await` that `Task` for ages without blocking any threads whatsoever.

`Task.Delay` for that matter is implemented very similarly with a `System.Threading.Timer` that completes the awaited task in its callback.

Answer (score 6):

> Aren't all "truly asynchronous" methods just blocking operations on some other thread if you dig deep enough?

On the contrary. Truely asynchronous methods are async all the way down to the OS level. These types of methods by default dont block even at the device driver level, using IRP (IO request packet) and DPC.

See [How does running several tasks asynchronously on UI thread using async/await work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009151/how-does-running-several-tasks-asynchronously-on-ui-thread-using-async-await-wor/28009458#28009458) where i went into detail as of how overlapped IO works all the way down.

> How then is it possible to achieve true asynchrony, like the various methods in System.Threading.Tasks.Task?

A `Task` represents a unit of work which will complete in *the future*. This has nothing to do with async IO. The reason you *might* assume that is because `async-await` works together nicely with *awaitables*. Most of the BCL libraries expose async IO operations via the `TaskAwaiter`, and that's why you assume it is the one achieving the asynchrony.