# Entity Framework SQL Server Compact poor query performance with nested select

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

So following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675265/blocking-behaviour-with-entity-framework-async-methods-and-sql-server-compact) question, I was looking into why I was seeing poor query performance with SQL Server Compact that was blocking the UI thread.  I have LazyLoading disabled and explicitly load the data that I need ahead of time.

To isolate this a little, I ran a test using the following query on the Northwind database to load all *Orders*, and for each *Order* load the associated *OrderDetails*, and for each *OrderDetail* load the *Product* and *Supplier*:

```
entities.Orders.Include(o => o.Order_Details
                        .Select(od => od.Products.Suppliers))
                .Load();
```

It took around 9 seconds to execute!

As a comparison I ran this against the Northwind database on my local SQL Server Express and it completed in < 0.1 seconds.

What is wrong with the .Select() that is causing the issue in this query? Why is this select causing such a long execution time for SQL Server Compact, but is fine when ran against SQL Server?

Comment: Did you look at the generated SQL (using DbContext..Log) and analyze it with SQL Server Compact Toolbox?

Comment: @ErikEJ the SQL from both looks identical (although fieldnames between databases are different), but the main structure is identical. The execution plans are different, but I would expect them to be different due to the extra facilities that SQL Server provides. Nothing out of the ordinary...

Comment: Have you checked the underlying tables to compare # of records, indexes and if there are any triggers on the tables?  Any of those things could affect query performance.

Comment: One more thing... If you manually run the generated SQL, do you see the same results as you get from going through EF?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @DeadZone.  This particular query/database is just for an example (the database is available publicly). I am experiencing the problem across all SQL compact databases where I eager load sub-entities by using the .Include(....Select(...)) type pattern